# Are saves from FF7 for PC (1998) compatible with FF7 on Steam (2013)?

Tags: final-fantasy-7, windows

Having played Final Fantasy 7 on PC years ago, I have an old save I want to continue. Is it possibly to transfer my save files from that version to the Steam one? Is it compatible?

Comment: Adding a comment instead of an answer because I don't know 100% -- but have you tried overwriting your local saves with your backups, and seeing if they work? That would be simplest method to test your question.

Comment: I don't have that option sadly. My saves are stored on a primitive CD and not with me at this moment. The question is more for pure curiosity as the steam version seems to be a very similar port to the old PC version.

Comment: @Dycker Is this actually "pure" curiosity, or is this gathering intel for a purchasing decision?

Comment: When I asked the question it was curiousity. I own the steam and older PC version and was wondering if it would work. After encountering a bug I mention below in my answer, it became kinda important to find out.

Comment: Be careful that you don't copy in your old save and then the game downloads new ones over the top!

Comment: Not related to the question, but @Dycker: you might want consider accepting some of the answers on your FF VII questions.  There are plenty of good ones :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Different versions of the game are not, but can be made compatible** (with help from  a program)

I found a program, [Black Chocobo](http://blackchocobo.sourceforge.net/), that allows to make the files compatible between many different versions including the steam version, old PC version, PlayStation save version, etc.

The program advertises compatibility between different formats and with the time I've done checking it out. It can save to save files for multiple consoles in multiple formats.

Comment: After encountering a game breaking glitch (and no backup saves to pull out cause I forgot to make copies...) I went looking and found this. I managed to load my old save file, change a small attribute, and went along my merry (unstuck) way on my game. Very helpful!

Comment: If they need a 3rd-party program to convert saves, then they aren't compatible. Just saying.

Comment: @kotekzot - So just "are" to "can be made" and the statement is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound I felt it was too radical a change to just it unilaterally.