# Can I copy my save game from Square Enix (2012) version to Steam (2013) version?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I bought FF7 direct from Square Enix when the remastered edition was first released. Today I bought it on Steam.

Is it possible to copy or transfer my saves across between these two versions?

I can see them both in my Square Enix account.

[image]

I've also found both the save directories, but copying the file between the folders and then running the Steam version seems to delete the savegame.

[image]

Comment: Related, perhaps dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133611/are-saves-from-ff7-for-pc-1998-compatible-with-ff7-on-steam-2013

Comment: @fbueckert The save games from the SE version are cloud saved, so I don't believe it's a duplicate, as the SE version is the same as the Steam version without the Steam support. SE version is this one, https://store.eu.square-enix.com/emea_uk/games/pc-windows-download/FINAL-FANTASY-VII.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the savegame files can be copied between versions.

The path of the savegames is here `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Square Enix\FINAL FANTASY VII\user_<SquareEnix_id>` and `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Square Enix\FINAL FANTASY VII Steam\user_<SquareEnix_id>` respectivly.

You need to copy **all** the files from the SquareEnix version across into the Steam version. It's also worth noting that you should run the game without cloud saving on to make sure that files are working before you turn on the cloud saving.

Once you've got the game running you can then sync the new files up the cloud, hopefully allowing continued progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to keep some saved games that happened to be local only and kept being erased by the cloud sync, I was able to keep them by saving to an unused "slot" inside the game then turning cloud sync on, it erased my first slot but kept my more recent second slot from my local copy, then I was able to save and sync.